# Create Trigger in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I want to create a Trigger on the Oracle SQLDeveloper.

The trigger should only allow the 'grade' column within the 'exams' table to get altered afterwards, IF the data in the grade column is below 4.0 aka 5.0/6.0 (German Grading System).

IF the data in the grade column is at 1.0/ 2.0/ 3.0/4.0, the Trigger should deny an alteration.

So the Trigger should check if the grade is below or above 4.0 and based on that, either allow or deny an alteration to the existent table data.

My main problem is that I don't quite understand the Syntax of a Trigger Creation for Oracle SQL Developer. Creating Constraints seems easy but Triggers have me confused.

Solutions I am trying to get to  work :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KlausurWiederholung
BEFORE UPDATE OF Note ON Prüfen
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF NEW.Note > OLD.Note THEN UPDATE Prüfen
END IF;
END
```

So if anyone could explain or link an useful example of how to correctly structure my Trigger, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi , check this link for an example for how to create a trigger, you will be using the :NEW variable to compare the data.   https://mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-plsql-after-update-trigger-example/

Comment: Or start with [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-217E8B13-29EF-45F3-8D0F-2384F9F1D231)? If you're trying to (maybe) prevent an existing value being modified then you'll need a `before update` trigger, not `before insert`.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you I have now reformatted my code, as you can see in my edit of the question. Getting nearer to the solution :)

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a desktop IDE. Trigger syntax doesn't depend on any particular tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `:OLD` and `:NEW` to refer to the row's records before and after the update and if the update is invalid then you want to raise an exception (and you need `;` as a statement terminator for the final `END` and to terminate the PL/SQL block with `/` on a new line):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER KlausurWiederholung
BEFORE UPDATE OF Note ON Prüfen
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF :OLD.Note <= 4.0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Grade too high to update.');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Then, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Prüfen (id, note) AS
SELECT  1, 1   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 1.2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 2   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2.5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 3   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 4   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 4.4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 5   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 5.7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 6   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 6.3 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
UPDATE Prüfen
SET   note = 1
WHERE id = 2;
```

Gives the exception:

> ```
> ORA-20000: Grade too high to update.
> ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_DPBZKTZLAVYIZCPLKBSE.KLAUSURWIEDERHOLUNG", line 3
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_DPBZKTZLAVYIZCPLKBSE.KLAUSURWIEDERHOLUNG'
> ```

But:

```
UPDATE Prüfen
SET   note = note + 4
WHERE note > 4;
```

Works.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1XkbhRSo)

Comment: Thank you for your solution, this solves my problem! I didn't know raising an application error message was possible, if possible could you link me a source you know where I can read up more on that?

Comment: @Alexy Look in the [official Oracle documentation for PL/SQL Error Handling](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-66346B68-7A18-438C-951B-A60F970D98B8)